# After update data with ajax i lose a property in a bootstrap button and a modal doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I'm working on a project with django and for ajax calls take as an example the project of: https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/

I have a table where with the button **Ver Tratamiento** I can show the information of a treatment through a modal. Likewise, if a treatment does not have an end date, the **Cerrar Tratamiento** button is disabled.

This is what I see when I click the **Ver Tratamiento** button:

[image]

And here you can see the buttons to **Cerrar Tratamiento** button disabled:
[image]

The problem is that when I close a treatment, the information is saved correctly in the base, and it returns to the template, but if I want to see the treatment again when I click the button to see treatment the modal does not appear, and if I see the closing buttons, those that were previously disabled are now enabled.

This is what happens after saving the treatment lock: [image]

This is the function I use to close the treatment:

```
    function cerrarTratamientoModalForm() {
      $(".cerrar-tratamiento").each(function () {
      $(this).modalForm({
        formURL: $(this).data("form-url"),
        asyncUpdate: true,
        asyncSettings: {
        closeOnSubmit: true,
        successMessage: asyncSuccessMessage,
        dataUrl: "/tratamientos/{{paciente.id}}",
        dataElementId: "#tablaTratamiento",
        dataKey: "table",
        addModalFormFunction: cerrarTratamientoModalForm
        }
      });
    });
}
cerrarTratamientoModalForm();
```

And this is the function with which I handle the content after saving the data.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: asyncSettings.dataUrl,
    dataType: null,
    success: function (response) {
        // Update page
        $(asyncSettings.dataElementId).html(response[asyncSettings.dataKey]);
        
        // Add modalForm to trigger element after async page update
        if (asyncSettings.addModalFormFunction) {
            asyncSettings.addModalFormFunction();
        }

        if (asyncSettings.closeOnSubmit) {
            $(settings.modalID).modal("hide");
            
        } else {
            // Reload form
            $(settings.modalID).find(settings.modalContent).load(settings.formURL, function () {
                $(settings.modalForm).attr("action", settings.formURL);
                addEventHandlers(settings);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

`<td style="text-align:center;"><button type="button" id="verTratamiento" class="bs-modal btn btn-sm btn-success" data-form-url={% url 'verTratamiento' pk=item.pk %} style='font-size:14px'><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> </button></td>`

```
$(".bs-modal").each(function () {
$(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data("form-url")});           
});
```

They are my first steps with ajax, I have done some tests trying to refresh the table, but without satisfactory results.

Comment: Please add the code on how you are opening the modal the first time - is it just using the `data-target`  or is via jQuery ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping These are the parts of the code

Answer (score 0):

Binding modalForm only works once the element is present, you have to bind after the data is loaded.

```
table.on('draw', function () {
    $(".bs-modal").each(function () {
        $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data("form-url")});
    });
});
```

https://datatables.net/reference/event/